# mongo db query is very slow even it hit index and has no scanAndOrder

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Mongodb version is 2.0.

I have collection like this structure:

```
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fc1225eec13839b46f400e4"),
   "wb" : {
    "trip_plan" : [{
         "op_sta" : "242H",
         "in_tm" : ISODate("2012-07-30T018:00:00Z"),
         "out_tm" : ISODate("2012-07-30T19:02:00Z"),
      }, {
         "op_sta" : "10563",
         "in_tm" : ISODate("2012-07-30T20:00:00Z"),
         "out_tm" : ISODate("2012-07-30T21:00:00Z") 
       }, {
         "op_sta" : "10451",
        "in_tm" : ISODate("2012-07-31T06:00:00Z"),
        "out_tm" : ISODate("2012-07-31T08:00:00Z"),
      }]
  }
}
```

trip_plan arr is big. average length is about 30-40. but I have no way to get only matched record in version 2.0.
My application is kind of write heavy application.

collection stats like :

```
   {
    "ns" : "itcp.car_location",
    "count" : 476509,
    "size" : 11794651412,
    "avgObjSize" : 24752.21121112088,
    "storageSize" : 13324562416,
    "numExtents" : 34,
    "nindexes" : 17,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.009999999878954,
    "flags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 2178233568,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 22418592,
        "wb.wb_sn_1" : 19516112,
        "next_wb.wb_sn_1" : 7914368,
        "wb.trip_plan.op_sta_1_wb.trip_plan.in_trn_1_wb.trip_plan.in_orgn_dt_1" : 315757120,
        "next_wb.trip_plan.op_sta_1_next_wb.trip_plan.in_trn_1_next_wb.trip_plan.in_orgn_dt_1" : 84065632,
        "wb.trip_plan.op_sta_1_wb.trip_plan.out_trn_1_wb.trip_plan.out_orgn_dt_1" : 319387264,
        "next_wb.trip_plan.op_sta_1_next_wb.trip_plan.out_trn_1_next_wb.trip_plan.out_orgn_dt_1" : 95487504,
        "last_op-last_evt_type-status"" : 30758112,
        "modify_ts" : 22091552,
        "ActlInTrn" : 245263648,
        "ActlOutTrn" : 243301408,
        "eq_nr_init" : 23105376,
        "event_os_trn_orgnDt" : 97719552,
        "wb_ibTrn_os_ts" : 255475472,
        "wb_obTrn_os_ts" : 243056128,
        "next_wb_ibTrn_os_ts" : 76658176,
        "next_wb_ObTrn_os_ts" : 76257552
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

My Index like this :

```
wb_obTrn_os_ts       
{
"wb.trip_plan.op_sta" : 1,
"wb.trip_plan.out_tm":1
}
```

when I do the query by the below

```
 db.car_location.find({ "wb.trip_plan": {$elemMatch: {"op_sta" :"148H",  
        "out_tm" : {$gt: ISODate("2012-08-02T04:00:00.000Z"),       
        $lt: ISODate("2012-08-03T04:00:00.000Z")}}}} ).explain();
... ... {
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor wb_obTrn_os_ts",
    "nscanned" : 45624,
    "nscannedObjects" : 45624,
    "n" : 2889,
    "millis" : 378954,
    "nYields" : 3858,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "wb.trip_plan.op_sta" : [
            [
                "148H",
                "148H"
            ]
        ],
        "wb.trip_plan.out_tm" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

My mongodb server RAM is 16G .
from the explain , you can see it hitted index and has no scanAndOrder.
It takes too long to get result !!
I was already blocked by this issue for days!!

Thanks a lot for your rescue!!

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults locked % idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn            set repl       time
     1     50     26      0       6      48       0  76.3g   154g  11.9g    223     15.3          0       8|3     9|3   147k   525k    74 abc2g_repl_set    M   11:48:33
     0     57     40      0       3      44       0  76.3g   154g  11.9g    158     12.4          0       6|4     8|4   101k   624k    74 abc2g_repl_set    M   11:48:34
     0     43     30      0       2      36       0  76.3g   154g  11.9g     84     13.2          0       5|1     7|1    93k   442k    74 abc2g_repl_set    M   11:48:35
     0      5      6      0       6      17       0  76.3g   154g    12g    281      2.4          0       1|1     6|0    13k    63k    74 abc2g_repl_set    M   11:48:36
     0     38      9      0       7       8       0  76.3g   154g  12.1g    256      2.1          0       0|0     5|0    41k   183k    74 abc2g_repl_set    M   11:48:37
     0     44      0      0       0      29       0  76.3g   154g  12.1g    359        0          0       0|0     5|0     5k   208k    74 abc2g_repl_set    M   11:48:38
     0     17      0      0       0       1       0  76.3g   154g  12.1g    316        0          0       0|0     6|0     1k    74k    74 abc2g_repl_set    M   11:48:39
     0     27      3      0       2      11       0  76.3g   154g  12.2g    225      0.3          0       3|0     5|0    12k   161k    74 abc2g_repl_set    M   11:48:40
     0     29      5      0       4      11       0  76.3g   154g  12.2g    275      3.2          0       0|0     5|0    24k   251k    74 abc2g_repl_set    M   11:48:41
     0     42      7      0       6      27       0  76.3g   154g  12.2g    197     12.4          0       0|0     5|0    14k   245k    74 abc2g_repl_set    M   11:48:42
```

which part of information should I pay attention ?

Comment: If you run it twice in quick succession, does it run lots faster the second time? Also, can you give mongostat output while running the query/explain?

Comment: If you run it twice in quick succession, does it run lots faster the second time? yes. it is true, it is faster to get result the second time. I just appended the mongostat on the end of post . thanks a lot for help. the document size is kind of big, so I cannot get only field I want. Will that impact performance also ?

Comment: This does not really rescue you. Your doing a lot of page faults the first time around, the reason why it is fast the second time is because of LRU

Comment: so what is the reason of slow query for the first time?

Comment: You can also cross post this on mongodb-user I am sure there are people who might have ideas.

Comment: Nobody can resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

here is few quick query/try you can do

1. do you really want $elemMatch? ( you know best about how it is structured!)
2. Can you try aggregate ?  when having $and $elemMatch on two different field (in complex query)  Mongodb query optimizer is behaving weird.  You can try pipelining these two operation and it will be superfast (atleast in most of my queries, of similar type!)